# How to save file to user hard drive using Flash

Tags: flash, download

Does anyone have tips on how can I save a file to a user hard-drive using Flash and show its download progress? Is it even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542610/how-can-image-be-saved-directly-to-a-folder-with-jpgencoder-in-as3

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Lee, but I'm looking for something that will allow me to initiate a download of additional formats like *.zip,*.torrent,*.mp3, not just images.

Comment: Ah, ok. You can download any file from a URL and then save it - but not in one step. User needs to specify save location (for every save) as a security measure. The relevant classes to use are URLLoader for downloading (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and FileReference for saving (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html). The doc links have examples for using both - i dont have time to post a working answer right now :(

Answer (score 0):

As Lee mentioned in his comments above, it is possible to do it with the following AS3 classes:

You can download any file from a URL and then save it - but not in one step. User needs to specify save location (for every save) as a security measure. The relevant classes to use are URLLoader for downloading ([help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/…](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html)) and FileReference for saving ([help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/…](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html)). The doc links have examples for using both.